# Pressure relief valve putting out water

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

My water heater has been draining out large amounts of water which I understand is caused by the water temperature being to high. How do I address this issue so that it won’t continue?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How much is "large amounts"? What make/model of heater? Would you add a picture? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: If you have a cooking thermometer, let the hot water run for a bit at a sink closest to the WH and take it's temp until the thermometer quits going up.  It shouldn't be much more than 120 -130 degrees.  If it is, you have a defective thermostat on your water heater. Dangerous.   If not too hot, either the water pressure is too high, or your temp/pressure relief valve is not working right.

Answer (score 1):

if the water is dangerously hot it's probably the thermostat that needs attention , if it's warm or cold probably the valve itself or the pressure regulator.

Answer (score 1):

Flip the breaker and let the tank cool down.  If the water stops dripping your problem is probably the thermostat.  If it just slowed down it's probably time for a pressure relief valve.

Sometimes the seats in the pressure relief valves get some corrosion.  Try flipping the little lever a couple times.  Please be careful, moving the lever will cause a release of hot water from the discharge.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your temperature setting on the thermostats are at decent levels, then you either have a faulty "hi limit" switch on your top thermostat which would have to then be replaced or your pressure relief valve is faulty. If I had to guess based on experience, I'd say it was the thermostat. The bi-metal strip in the thermostat is more likely to get out of wack then the spring in the pressure relief valve.